# Уплывают слайды

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Суть проблемы:
Когда слайдер мотает на новый слайд, галлерея (навигация) снизу тоже листает слайд влево, чего просто не нужно. Надо чтобы также и оставалось 3 слайда снизу.

Плагин slick slider. Кто нибудь знает, как этого избежать ? Скрины ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$('.thio').slick({
infinite: true,
slidesToShow: 1,
slidesToScroll: 1,
autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed: 1000,
arrows: false,
fade: false,
adaptiveHeight: false,
asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: count,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.thio',
  dots: true,
  focusOnSelect: true,

});
```

Comment: Боюсь, это врядли возможно. Но советую поискать у них на сайте во вкладке Settings ответ: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: @DGDays сижу вот читаю как раз..вроде нет ничего..придется в исходник лезть наверное

Comment: вот я тоже вроде всё перерыл, но ничего об этом не увидел

Comment: @DGDays самое интересное, что если переключаться между слайдами через эту панель навигации, то все гуд..если autoplay то печалька..не учли мб

Comment: Ну, возможно... Я этой библиотекой всего один раз пользовался, чаще всего юзаю bxSlider. Правда, у него нету вот такой вариации как в slick, но если есть голова - минут за 30 можно что-то похожее написать

Comment: Добавьте ваш код

Comment: @HamSter добавил..

Comment: @sousage1212, ```slidesToShow: count``` чему равно count?

Comment: @HamSter числу изображений для данного товара. В данном  случае - 5

Comment: @sousage1212, тогда для второго можно и infinite: false задать. у меня не уезжает https://jsbin.com/hiwosuc/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @HamSter Как не уезжает, если даже на Вашем примере слайды уезжают влево..